# Jquery array false to true and true to false ceases to continue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

**Page1: Initial Setup**

```
<?php
  $_POST["view"]=[
    "image"=>false
  ];
?>
<script>
  var listing
  $(".panel").on("click",function(event){
    listing["view"]["image"]=!listing["view"]["image"]
    $(".reload").load("Page2.php",listing)
  })
</script>
<div class="reload"><?php include"Page2.php";?></div>
```

On click it reloads a page with a $_POST variable based on js variable listing

**Page2: Jquery Load Page**
gets $_POST from load event

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
<script>
  listing=<?=json_encode($_POST)?>;
  ...
</script>
```

**Before any click:** `Array ( [view] => Array ( [image] => ) )`

**1st click:** `Array ( [view] => Array ( [image] => true ) )`

**2nd click:** `Array ( [view] => Array ( [image] => false ) )`

**After 2nd click:** `Array ( [view] => Array ( [image] => false ) )`

Then it is stuck on false. False will not turn into true again. Why is this happening?

**Possible Problem:**
The `listing=<?=json_encode($_POST)?>;` may be creating a string out of the bool? Is it possible for json to keep it bool.

The json_encode is as follows:

```
{"id":"mainListings","view":{"image":false}}
{"id":"mainListings","view":{"image":"true"}}
{"id":"mainListings","view":{"image":"false"}}
```

It will turn **"true"** into **"false"** but not **"false"** into **"true"**? Why is the bool not preserved with the encode?

Comment: can you please provide more code? in Page1, the very first php declaration has basically no effect whatsoever on your javascript code.

Comment: That php just creates a post variable affects a php include. First load is not loaded, it is php include. Then on click of the panel, that page is reloaded with new set of post variables

Comment: what happens if you do not include your page2.php in page1.php code? this: `<div class="reload"><?php include"Page2.php";?></div>` to this: `<div class="reload"></div>`

Comment: It just wont preload page. The include with the initial $_POST recreates a JS load without using JS. It makes the page initially load smoothly

Comment: When you post anything to php, it is sent as a string. Before performing any kind of operation on it, you should convert it to the proper type (maybe do `$_POST['view']['image'] = $_POST['view']['image'] === 'true';` before json_encode)